# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS headphone jack randomly playing videos / audios

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, headset

Whenever my earphones are connected and any video or audio player is paused in the background (mostly YouTube through web browser), it automatically resumes playing at random instances. This is very frequent as in every 20-30 seconds after pause but not in fixed intervals.

I know that hardware is not a problem as I have dual booted my device (windows and Ubuntu) and it works fine with Windows. And I am sure that the headphone is giving random signals which plays the video or audio.

I even tried `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start` code and   `sudo alsactl restore` found somewhere while searching for this problem but it didn't help.

If anyone knows how to resolve this please help